# Mongo access DB user rights

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Mongo 3.4
When I log into the admin db I can see my users:

```
> show users
{
    "_id" : "admin.jon",
    "user" : "jon",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "admin.bill",
    "user" : "bill",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWrite",
            "db" : "leads"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbOwner",
            "db" : "leads"
        }
    ]
}
```

Notice bill is the owner of the "leads" db and should have readWrite access to it.

However, when using Mongo Ruby driver via rails c on my production server, I try to list the collections and I get an error:

```
client  = Mongo::Client.new([Rails.application.secrets.mongo], user: 'bill', password: 'xxxxxx', database: "leads")
db = client.database
db.collections
 # => Mongo::Auth::Unauthorized (User bill (mechanism: scram) is not authorized to access leads (auth source: leads) (used mechanism: SCRAM-SHA-1): Authentication failed. (on localhost:xxxxx))
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Add `auth_source: admin` in the mongo client config. Your mongo user info is stored in the `admin` database and if you don't specify it via `auth_source` parameter, then the client tries to find the user info in the database you want to use for data. In this case it's the `leads` database.

Notice `(auth source: leads)` in the error